# Equivalent characterizations for Hausdorff in a first-countable space

Tags: general-topology, compactness, separation-axioms

Today a student came to me with the following exercise from a course in topology:

Suppose $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is first-countable. Show that the following are equivalent:

1. $X$ is Hausdorff
2. Every convergent sequence in $X$ converges to precisely one point
3. $X$ is T1 and every compact subset of $X$ is closed

I was able to show and explain all implications, except for one. 
I was not able to find a proof for $3. \Rightarrow 1$ or $3. \Rightarrow 2$.

Could someone explain to me how I should handle this implication? 
Or could someone give a hint which characterization of Hausdorff is most appropriate for this proof?

As always, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: 3. is redundant since every compact subset of $X$ being closed implies that points are closed, hence $X$ is $T_1$.

Answer (score 4):

To prove $3. \Rightarrow 2.$, consider a convergent sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, and let $x_\ast$ be any one of its limit points (we don't know yet that there is only one). The set

$$K = \{x_\ast\} \cup \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$$

is compact.

By $3.$, $K$ is closed. But any limit point of the sequence is contained in the closure of $\{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, so in particular in $K$.

For any $y \neq x_\ast$, consider a neighbourhood $U$ of $x_\ast$ that doesn't contain $y$ (that exists since the space is $T_1$), and the subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of terms that lie in $U$ to conclude that $(x_n)$ doesn't converge to $y$: the subsequence still converges to all limit points of the original sequence, and the corresponding compact set $K' = \{x_\ast\} \cup \{ x_{n_k} : k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ by construction does not contain $y$; Since $K'$ is closed, $y$ has a neighbourhood that doesn't contain any of the $x_{n_k}$.

Comment: +1, but I am not sure if I understand your last paragraph, so let me try another formulation. We have seen that $y$ has to be one of the $x_n$. But convergence of a sequence does not change if change finitely many elements of the sequence, so we must have $x_n=y$ for infinitely many $n$. But that means that every neighbourhood of $x$ contains $y$, hence $\{y\}$ is not closed. Maybe that was your argument.

Comment: Not quite. That works too, of course, but I've added the completion of the argument I had in mind.

Answer (score 2):

To see that $3. \Rightarrow 1.$, assume that $X$ is $T_1$ and all compact sets are closed. Suppose that $X$ is *not* Hausdorff, so there are two points $p,q \in X$ such that every neighbourhood of $p$ intersects every neighbourhood of $q$.

As $X$ is first countable, $p$ and $q$ have local neighbourhood bases $U_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $V_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ resp. that we can choose decreasingly, without loss of generality. Pick points $x_n \in U_n \cap V_n$ by the non-Hausdorffness. Then $(x_n) \rightarrow p$ and $(x_n) \rightarrow q$, as sequences. (Note that argument already shows that $2. \Rightarrow 1.$, by contrapositive.) The set $\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{p\}$ is compact (it's a convergent sequence) but not closed, as $q$ is in its closure but not in the set. So this would contradict $3.$, and so $X$ is Hausdorff.

As to $3. \Rightarrow 2.$: This last argument shows that if we have a sequence having two distinct limits, we have a compact set that is not closed (the sequence and one of the limits).